# Nginx not serving static files with docker-compose and django (13: Permission denied)

Tags: python, django, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose and docker-machine to setup a dev environment with multiple containers. I have a container for nginx, which acts as a proxy to my django application and also serves static files). I have also a container for the django app, one for postgresql and one for postgresdata.
The directory structure is the following:

```
code/
  -- nginx/
       Dockerfile
       nginx.conf
  -- web/
       django-project/
       static/
       Dockerfile
       manage.py
       requirements.txt
  .env
  docker-compose.yml
  production.yml
```

In order to run the application, I use docker-machine:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox dev
```

then I run:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

And the application is up and running on the ip of the machine. The problemm is that nginx cannot serve static files, because it hasn't the permission (13: Permission denied).

My setup is the following:

nginx Dockerfile:

```
# Set nginx base image
FROM nginx

# Copy custom configuration file from the current directory
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.org;

        access_log /dev/stdout;
        error_log /dev/stdout info;

        location /static/ {
            alias /usr/src/app/static/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web:8000;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

django Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5.1-onbuild
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/static
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn collecteev_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes_from:
    - data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"

data:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  command: "true"
```

Versions:

```
docker: 1.9.1
docker-compose: 1.5.2
docker-machine: 0.5.4
```

Any help with this problem would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for a well thought out question. It has good debugging information. One thing that jumps out at me is the mounting `/usr/src/app/static` in the web container is happening _after_ the build of the image, which will overwrite the static folder already there (essentially making an empty folder). Nginx could be giving a permission denied not because it can't read the folder, but because it is empty. Can you bring up the stack, and do a `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` into the web container and confirm the permissions on the static folder and that it has content in it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! here its the permissions on the static folder:

    `drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   80 Jan 23 20:43 static`

There is the 'admin' folder inside, that are the static files grabbed from:

    `docker-compose run web /usr/local/bin/python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

but there is no trace of my 'web/static' folder

Comment: Just add permissions and output from each the nginx and web container to the original question.

Comment: From the nginx container is the same thing: same permissions, same files inside the static folder, but no files from my 'web/static' folder

Comment: @AndyShinn I solved the issue of PermissionDenied by modifying the permissions in the folder like you suggested, thanks for that!

Comment: Strange, I built a similar test locally (small Django app with a static folder behind nginx) and it works fine without needing permission changes. Both containers are using root as the user and have 755 for folder permissions.

Comment: Yeah, probably I messed up something in the configs. Now I have another problem, the static folder inside 'web' collide with the static folder produced by 'django collectstatic'. I temporarily solved it by adding the following line to  django Dockerfile:

    `VOLUME /usr/src/app/static`

and then modifying this line in docker-compose.yml:

    `web:
         - volumes: /usr/src/app/static2`

and then I merge the folder static2 into static from docker exec. Do you have a better solution?